# Inserting HTML data in mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have written a HTML form filling page(sample.html), and also I have written a PHP (sample.php) code for inserting data from HTML page , but i could not receive the Correct message to me, please explain anybody else!!!

Here is the php code:-

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');

if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db( "selva",$connection);

if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

error_reporting(0);

session_start();

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$father_name = $_POST['father_name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
$sports = $_POST['sports'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($first_name!='' and $father_name!='' and $gender!='' and $date_of_birth!='' and $sports!='' and $mobile!='' and $email!='') {

     $query = mysql_query("insert into register(first_name, father_name, gender, date_of_birth, sports, mobile, email) values('$first_name', '$father_name', '$gender', '$date_of_birth','$sports','$mobile','$email')");

     echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";

 } else {
     echo "<p>Failed to Insert data <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
 }

 mysql_close($connection); 

 ?>
```

Please tell how to insert the data from HTML page to database??

Comment: Can you please provide any errors? What's going wrong.
And a tip, please use MySQLi (if possible) and sanitize your query, this is injectable as hell ;)

Comment: You should not use `mysql_` functions. Never. [That's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046).

Comment: are u using `sample.php` in `<form action="sample.php" method="post">` ??

Comment: You can use mysqli_      reffer https://www.eduonix.com/blog/web-programming-tutorials/learn-submit-html-data-mysql-database-using-php/

Comment: The error is when i enter the data in Xampp as localhost after clicking the submit button i receive php code in html page

Comment: yes <form action="sample.php" method="post">this is used in html page

Comment: than u must need to check your your file extension and form action

Comment: i have checked two to three times i can't get it

Comment: sample.php avaialble on same root? plz check the extension of sample file

Answer (score 0):

try to this..

```
use <form action="sample.php" method="post">

<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');

if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
} else {
    $select_db = mysqli_select_db( "selva",$connection);

    if (!$select_db){
        die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
    } else {
        error_reporting(0);

        session_start();

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $father_name = $_POST['father_name'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
        $sports = $_POST['sports'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if($first_name!='' and $father_name!='' and $gender!='' and $date_of_birth!='' and $sports!='' and $mobile!='' and $email!='') {

           mysqli_query($connection, "insert into register(first_name, father_name, gender, date_of_birth, sports, mobile, email) values('$first_name', '$father_name', '$gender', '$date_of_birth','$sports','$mobile','$email')");

            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
                echo "<p>Data Successfully add Added</p>";
            } else {
                echo "Employee NOT Added<br />";
                echo mysqli_error ($connection);
            }
         } else {
             echo "<p>Failed to Insert data <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
         }

         mysql_close($connection);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Reffer this link. i think this is usefull for you...
https://www.eduonix.com/blog/web-programming-tutorials/learn-submit-html-data-mysql-database-using-php/